# pyqt5 autocomplete QLineEdit - Google places autocomplete

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlineedit, qcompleter

I am trying to create something like this (autocomplete places) in pyqt5 QLineEdit.

[image]

[image]

There is a class called QCompleter with which i can suggest the content, but it requires an already formed list, but this google places api is a suggestion based function, how can i send each keystroke to google api and get the suggestion back and load in Qtextedit, is there a better way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case you can create a custom model that makes a request using [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete), and set that model to a QCompleter:

```
import json
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtNetwork

API_KEY = "<API_KEY>"

class SuggestionPlaceModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    error = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SuggestionPlaceModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._manager = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager(self)
        self._reply = None

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def search(self, text):
        self.clear()
        if self._reply is not None:
            self._reply.abort()
        if text:
            r = self.create_request(text)
            self._reply = self._manager.get(r)
            self._reply.finished.connect(self.on_finished)
        loop = QtCore.QEventLoop()
        self.finished.connect(loop.quit)
        loop.exec_()

    def create_request(self, text):
        url = QtCore.QUrl("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json")
        query = QtCore.QUrlQuery()
        query.addQueryItem("key", API_KEY)
        query.addQueryItem("input", text)
        query.addQueryItem("types", "geocode")
        query.addQueryItem("language", "en")
        url.setQuery(query)
        request = QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(url)
        return request

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_finished(self):
        reply = self.sender()
        if reply.error() == QtNetwork.QNetworkReply.NoError:
            data = json.loads(reply.readAll().data())
            if data['status'] == 'OK':
                for prediction in data['predictions']:
                    self.appendRow(QtGui.QStandardItem(prediction['description']))
            self.error.emit(data['status'])
        self.finished.emit()
        reply.deleteLater()
        self._reply = None

class Completer(QtWidgets.QCompleter):
    def splitPath(self, path):
        self.model().search(path)
        return super(Completer, self).splitPath(path)

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        self._model = SuggestionPlaceModel(self)
        completer = Completer(self, caseSensitivity=QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        completer.setModel(self._model)
        lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        lineedit.setCompleter(completer)
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self._model.error.connect(label.setText)
        lay = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self)
        lay.addRow("Location: ", lineedit)
        lay.addRow("Error: ", label)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.resize(400, w.sizeHint().height())
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: wow, all your answers have been awesome in python space..you are a genius. Thanks again.. is there a way to throttle the requests? i am getting over query limit error

Comment: hi, @eyllanesc I tried your answer, the request is fine, but it seems the list is not showing up in the line edit. I only get the error message (in this case it is ok). Any suggestions for this issue? Thanks

Comment: @ismailsunni What error message do you mean? You could also point out that you have entered the QLineEdit. Finally add `print(reply.errorString(), reply.error())` after `reply = self.sender()` to see if there are any errors.

Comment: hi @eyllanesc. There is no error from the request. The request is fine (I have checked it i.e. write it to file). It is just the pop up / list of option is not showing up. Is there any method to call to show the list?

Comment: @ismailsunni What version of pyqt5 are you using, how did you install it and what is your OS?

Comment: @eyllanesc I am running the code for a plugin. I have checked the version of pyqt5, it is 5.14.2. The Qt is also 5.14.2. Is there any difference in this python version?

Comment: @ismailsunni 1) Depending on how you got it and what PyQt5 you use there may be bugs, so I need some information. 2) I just tested my code and it works. 3) what do you mean by plugin? I can only answer for my code by itself without integrations, since if you integrate it to another SW I cannot guarantee that it works. Have you only tested my code? 4) I could help you more if you provide me with an APIKEY since at this moment I don't have one.

Comment: Hi @eyllanesc. I tested your code with my PyQt 5.10.1, it's working fine. It seems the problem is within the python or PyQt version that is used in the application. I am creating a plugin for a Qt-based application. The plugin is created by using the Python API (PyQt) provided by the application.

Comment: hi @eyllanesc, just to let you know, it's working within the application. I am not sure what's my mistake in the previous trial. Anyway, it's working now. So, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, at first I tried @eyllanasec's answer. But for some reason, the performance is not so good (often stuck or hang) in the platform that I use (I was creating a plugin for Qt-based software using PyQt). It is running fine independently though, so perhaps it's specific to my platform.

In the end, I found a Qt example project for a similar case, **Google Suggest**. You can find it https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-googlesuggest-example.html. It creates a custom class to handle the search and the pop-up window (using QTreeWidget).

Since the example is in Qt, I port it to PyQt with small modification https://github.com/ismailsunni/scripts/blob/master/autocomplete_from_url.py

Comment: This makes sense because `self.model().search(path)` inside `splitPath` will block until the request completes.